# Bootstrap Form and PHP

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have changed the wording to maybe be more clear about what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm assuming I'll need Javascript in order to make this work, I'm just not sure how to employ it.  Thoughts?

```
    //the user will make a selection from the following dropdown
    <div class="form-group col-lg-offset-3">
                <h3>
                    <select id="flavor" name="id">
                        <option name="flavor">Select FLAVOR</option>
                        <option name="1">FRUIT PUNCH</option>
                        <option name="2">GRAPE</option>
                        <option name="3">WATERMELON</option>
                    </select>
                </h3>
            </div>

    //based on the user selection, the option name (i.e. 1, 2, 3) must go after cartAction.php?action=addToCart&id=
            <a href="cartAction.php?action=addToCart&id=">
                <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" button type="button" class="btn btn-success center-block button-buffer">
            </a>
```

So, for example, if the user selects FRUIT PUNCH, then a href section will look like:

```
    <a href="cartAction.php?action=addToCart&id=1">
                <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" button type="button" class="btn btn-success center-block button-buffer">
            </a>
```

Comment: do not spam with irrelevant tags. Your question is not related to mysql nor php at all

Comment: Actually, it is relevant to php as the action is to a php page.  The original action involved php code, but I'm attempting to modify it.  All of the option values are actually equivalent to values in a mysql database.  Thanks for your very helpful answer Marcin.

Answer (score 1):

you have to give name select   `<select id="flavor" name="selectItem">`

```
 <select id="flavor" name="selectItem">
       <option name="flavor">Select FLAVOR</option>
       <option name="0">FRUIT PUNCH</option>
       <option name="1">GRAPE</option>
       <option name="2">WATERMELON</option>
 </select>
```

so you can pass option value to other page

and then you can access using `GET` or `POST` method

```
$item=$_GET['selectItem'];
```

Updated

```
 <form action="cartAction.php?action=addToCart&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
  <select id="flavor" name="selectItem"> 
    <option name="flavor">Select FLAVOR</option> 
    <option name="0">FRUIT PUNCH</option> 
    <option name="1">GRAPE</option> 
    <option name="2">WATERMELON</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" button type="button" class="btn btn-success center-block button-buffer"> 
</form>
```

Comment: It's on the same page though and whatever option is chosen has to be passed through the form action.  I tried your suggestion, but nothing is happening.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MatthewSpire.you should  keep select in between form not outside the form

Comment: <form action="cartAction.php?action=addToCart&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> <select id="flavor" name="selectItem">
                            <option name="flavor">Select FLAVOR</option>
                            <option name="0">FRUIT PUNCH</option>
                            <option name="1">GRAPE</option>
                            <option name="2">WATERMELON</option>
                        </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" button type="button" class="btn btn-success center-block button-buffer">
    </form>

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your post and add new information there so it is more readable.

Comment: @JayBlanchard.Thanks sorry for that mistake

Comment: Okay, still not working.  The issue is that where it says <?php echo $row["id"]; ?> in the form action, that area is not getting updated with the selection the user chooses.  Is there any way to update that area before the user clicks on the button?

Comment: Dont you mean echo $item in your href?

Comment: The original code of the href had id=<?php echo #row["id"] ?>.  I removed that though because it wasn't working and because I need to know how to get a client side choice into that action.